# $\frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{(x^2)}$ is a local ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I would like to prove if $\frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{(x^2)}$ is local ring.  I think it do is a local ring, since $x^2 $ might be a maximal idea, but I do not how to express it, since I am trying to explore localization by myself. So I will really appreciate any help.  Thank you so much.

Comment: $(x^{2})$ isn't a maximal ideal, because $(x^{2})=(0)$ and $(0)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ if and only if $R$ is a field, but $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{2})$ isn't a field.

Comment: A local ring has a unique maximal ideal. Since $(x^2) \subset (x) \subset (p,x)$ for every prime $p$, and $(p,x)$ is maximal in $\mathbf Z[x]$, the ring $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2)$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.  On the other hand, if $K$ is a field then the only maximal ideal of $K[x]$ containing $(x^2)$ is $(x)$, so $K[x]/(x^2)$ is a local ring.

Answer (score 1):

I like thinking of maximal ideals as maps to fields (this is really just a restatement of @KCd's comment). Any map out of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ is determined where $1$ and $x$ are sent. Can you think of any maps from this ring to, say, a finite field? Is the size of the finite field relevant?